# Provide non-singleton service in module

Tags: angular6, angular2-services

Is it possible to provide a service in a module so that it creates a new instance whenever it is injected?

I know I can provide it in a component's decorator and it will create new instances, but I cannot use that method in my case. My module looks something like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [/* ... */ ],
  declarations: [ /* ... */ ],
  providers: [ /* ... */ ]
})
export class MyModule {
  static useCustomService(service: any) {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        service,
        {
          provide: SomeService,
          useClass: service // <--- don't want this to be a singleton
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is a reusable library where I would like to inject a custom service to replace the default. I'd really like to avoid refactoring the service so that it works as a singleton.

**Update**

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyy3qt) to demonstrate. This is not my real use case. I adapted an example from Angular's documentation.

Comment: useFactory and provide a function that creates a new instance each time?

Comment: It's a good thought, but it still appears to create a singleton. I'm thinking maybe the factory is only run once when the module is imported.